# Uploading image with status to Twitter using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am using a function called `prepare_access_token` to contact Twitter api to perform Read, Write functions.

Below is the code i use to update twitter message

```
@tweet = "Rails Rails"
@access_token = prepare_access_token(@oauth_token, @oauth_secret)
@response = @access_token.request(:post, "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json", :status => @tweet)
```

```
def prepare_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

  consumer_key = Rails.application.config.consumer_key
  consumer_secret = Rails.application.config.consumer_secret  

  consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
    { :site => "http://api.twitter.com",
      :scheme => :header
    })
  # now create the access token object from passed values
  token_hash = { :oauth_token => oauth_token,
                 :oauth_token_secret => oauth_token_secret
               }
  access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash )
  return access_token
end
```

This works for status update without attached image , but when i try to update status with image attachment like below

```
@access_token = prepare_access_token(@oauth_token, @oauth_secret)
@response = @access_token.request(:post,  "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"  , :media => $image , :status  => "Status")
```

it shows like `{"request":"/1/statuses/update_with_media.json","error":"Error creating status."}`

what am i doing wrong? please suggest.

Comment: Have you get the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For the consumer:site, try setting it to http://upload.twitter.com instead of http://api.twitter.com. the api site does not support media upload.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other REST methods to the Twitter API, you have to set the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` for this `POST https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json` method.

Comment: how can i set this with this request call..
i tried using `:content-type => "multipart/form-data"` but no luck!!

Comment: I just know about the Twitter API, not RoR. `Content-Type` is an HTTP header, so I guess that you do like other HTTP headers in HTTP requests.

Comment: Ok.. but even after setting content type - the same error
`@response = @access_token.post("https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json", { :status => "stat", :media => @image }, {'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'})`