# How to update Twitter status with image in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to use twitter api `https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json`
to post tweet along with image (with OAuth). But i am continuously facing issues with uploading image for the past 3 days.

I have posted my question in StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390253/uploading-image-with-status-to-twitter-using-rails/11395955#11395955). But cannot able to find a solution.

Do i have to use anyother method to achieve this?

Comment: which gem are you using?

Comment: OAuth gem.. i have briefed what i have used in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390253/uploading-image-with-status-to-twitter-using-rails/11395955#11395955